# how to point all domains on server to one particular database

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

my requirement is like this 
on my server i have 4 domains which all have same functionalists. with single admin.

All the domain oriented manipulation has to be done from single database. that single database will be there in one domain.

Scripting language i'm using is PHP.

Example :

www.1domain.com (which has database for all domains).

www.2domain.com (which should uses www.1domain.com database)

www.3domain.com (which should uses www.1domain.com database)

www.4domain.com (which should uses www.1domain.com database)

Answer (score 0):

You just need in each domain php code insert same database configuration (username, password, host(server address)) and thats all - it doesnt matter on which domain user enters - database configuration is writen in the files and you may edit that and force any code (almost;P) to use the database you want. There is no need to change cpanel - **just go to** (probably) **`config.php` of the pages you have on each domain and provide the same database connection credentials.**